# I want to make Atom Reader with Python

Tags: php, python, feed

I'm trying to make an Atom Reader (0.3) with Python.

I'm familiar with php and I want some equivalent commands in python.

If I were using php, I would use file_get_contents and parse those Atom from it.

Maybe use Simplexml parser.

Is there equivalent commands like $file_get_contents?

Also I have downloaded Universal Feed Reader (Python RSS/Atom Reader Module)

But I cannot find any example on it.

I want to see at least example of using Universal Feed Reader.

Comment: I'm sure you meant the `file_get_contents` function, not the variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation of [Universal Feed Parser](http://www.feedparser.org/). The frontpage is nothing but examples:

```
>>> import feedparser
>>> d = feedparser.parse("http://feedparser.org/docs/examples/atom10.xml")
>>> d['feed']['title']             # feed data is a dictionary
u'Sample Feed'
```